# Third derivative of a function at a maximum point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions and  $f - g$ has a maximum point at $x_0$. Then we have $$f'(x_0) = g'(x_0)$$ $$f''(x_0) \le g''(x_0).$$

- In general what can we say about the third derivatives?
- Under what reasonable additional assumptions on $f$ and $g$ can we deduce one inequality $f'''(x_0) \le g'''(x_0)$ or $f'''(x_0) \ge g'''(x_0)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)<g^{\prime\prime}(x_0)$ then you cannot conclude anything on the third derivative. Take $f(x)=-x^2+ax^3$ and $g=0$. Then $f-g$ has a local maximum at $x=0$ and the sign of $a$ can be anything. 
If  $f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)=g^{\prime\prime}(x_0)$, then $f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_0)=g^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_0)$, since by Taylor's formula
$$(f-g)(x)=(f-g)(x_0)+\frac1{3!}(f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_0)-g^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_0))(x-x_0)^3+\text{o}(x-x_0)^3$$ and $(x-x_0)^3$ changes sign depending on $x>x_0$ or $x<x_0$.

Comment: When do we have $f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)=g^{\prime\prime}(x_0)$?

Comment: There are many cases. For example, take $f(x)=-x^4$ and $g=0$. Then $f^{\prime\prime}(0)=g^{\prime\prime}(0)=0$.

Comment: I mean, what kind of functions satisfy this condition? That is, what does this condition tell us about the nature of the maximum point?

Comment: Call $h=f-g$. Then all functions $h$ that near $x_0$ behave like a polynomial of degree $4$ or more generally of degree $2n$ with $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Why is that so?  Can the maximum be strict under such conditions? And how does this translate in terms of functions $f$ and $g$? That is, what conditions should one impose on $f$ and $g$ so that $f''(x_0)=g''(x_0)$?

Comment: the maximum of $f(x)=-x^4$ and $g=0$ is strict. Just write down Taylor's formula for $f$ and for $g$ and subtract them. Near $x_0$ you have that $f$ and $g$ behave like polynomials and you are just asking that the first coefficients are the same.   I don't know how to answer your question more than I have already done. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Here I've asked a related question that might interest you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333412/third-derivative-estimates-for-sequence-of-functions-at-a-maximum-point